# socks proxy for debian lenny? dante not works

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

hello I need a socks5 proxy for debian with simple configuration. dante not working. p.s: I do NOT wish to use SSH tunneling.

Comment: note that lenny is EOL and no longer supported.  It has well known security vulnerabilities that nobody is going to fix.  It is recommended you upgrade to squeeze (by following chapter 4 of the squeeze release notes).

Answer (score 2):

Dante on lenny seems to be a known issue. try

> nano /etc/apt/sources.list (change "lenny" to "etch" )
>
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install dante-server
>
> nano /etc/apt/sources.list (change "etch" back to "lenny")
>
> apt-get clean

And make sure you configured dante correctly (the default config *should* fail)

As an alternative you could use `sockd`, check out `apt-get install socks4-server` & `man sockd`

Or when v5 is a must take a look at `tsocks`

Comment: not works      ..............

Comment: deeper? logs logs logs... "not works" as in "i can connect but cant reach the internet anymore" or as in "when i press enter on the start command my computer explodes, northkorea fixes the missle thing and your gradfather starts running arround naked"?

Comment: apt-get failed and can not get package

Comment: E: Couldn't find package dante-server

Comment: update.your.system. thx =(  (you notice a ton of 404s when doing `apt-get update`, dont you?)

Comment: yes I get lot of errors and apt-get do not works (could not get package)

Comment: there you go http://superuser.com/questions/404806/debian-lenny-repositories-vanished